# Google+ photos to edit (possibly through Google Drive)

Tags: google-drive, google-plus, google-plus-photos, image-storage

I do not understand why pictures that I do not want to edit are editable in Google+ whereas those which I do want to edit are not editable. I do not see Edit button for them. I hear that Google Drive/Docs may have apps for image editing. Maybe I am more lucky there.

But how can I import the Google+ photos to Google Drive?

Answer (score 1):

From [How Google Drive works with Google Photos - Drive Help](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/6156103?hl=en)

> You can view and manage your photos and videos in both Google Photos
> and Google Drive. You can also create a Google Photos folder in your
> "My Drive," to organize your photos and videos into folders. Photos
> and videos that you can see in both Google Photos and Drive only count
> once in your Google storage space.

---

> ### View your Google Photos library in Google Drive
>
> Your Google Photos library includes everything that's been backed up
> or uploaded using Google+ Photos or Google Photos.
>
> In Google Drive, you can move your photos and videos from your Google
> Photos library into folders. Note that the folder names and
> organization you create in Google Drive will not be reflected in
> Google Photos.

---

> #### Computer
>
> 1. Go to [drive.google.com](http://drive.google.com).
> 2. Click Google Photos on the left.

---

> ### Take action on your photos & videos in Drive
>
> From the "Google Photos" section in Drive, you can take a number of different actions
> on the items that appear.

---

> #### Computer
>
> 1. Go to drive.google.com.
> 2. Click Google Photos on the left.
> 3. Place your cursor over a photo to:
>
>    - Download [image: Download]: Download the photo to your device
>    - Save to Drive [image: Save to Drive]: Save a copy of the photo to My Drive. This allows you to organize the photo, and other files, the way you want.
>    - Other actions [image: Other option]: Choose from a number of options:
>
>      - Open with another application
>      - Share
>      - Star as important
>      - Rename
>      - Make a copy
>      - Remove from Drive and Google Photos